# @font-face not display for block items on MAC (Chrome/Safari)

Tags: css, macos, safari, font-face

I am having issues formatting any block elements with an embedded font in Safari and Chrome on a Mac.
Formatting is correct for all windows browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome even Safari), and the font correctly displays for inline elements. I have stripped the html to just the following basics and still having this issue - What am I missing ??

```
@font-face { font-family: yowieFont; src: url(/template/GROBOLD.ttf); font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-variant:normal;}
h1 { font-family: yowieFont; color: #ed2249;}
h2 { font-family: yowieFont; color: #ed2249;}
h3 { font-family: yowieFont; color: #ed2249;}
p { font-family: yowieFont; color: #ed2249;}
span { font-family: yowieFont; color: #ed2249;}

<h1 style="display: inline;">1: CONTACT US</h1>
<h1 >1: CONTACT US</h1>
<h2 >2: CONTACT US</h2>
<h3 >3: CONTACT US</h3>
<p >P: CONTACT US</p>
<span>span: CONTACT US</span>
```

Comment: You are missing your other font files. You need `.svg`, `.eot`, `.woff` and `.ttf`.

Comment: @drip Read the question again. The OP says it works fine for the span, but not for the other elements.

Comment: I had originally thought the issue was with the font, but as it displayed for inline elements I did not understand why. However putting the font through the fontsquirrel tool did indeed fix this issue

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by running the font through the font squirrel tool:
fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

The tool generated the differing web formats required and fixed the line-height issues I was also having with this font

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'yowieFont';
  src: url('/template/grobold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('/template/grobold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('/template/grobold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('/template/grobold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),    
  url('/template/grobold-webfont.svg#groboldmedium') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```